# Can you identify this scale? C Db Eb G Ab C

Tags: theory, scales

Can you identify this scale? C Db Eb G Ab C

Comment: Is this a homework question? What context do you have for it? What research have you done so far?

Comment: Why is that collection of pitches necessarily a scale?

Comment: Welcome! Please tell us more about where you found it and why you're wondering, and maybe also what you understand a "scale" to mean (there are different uses in different contexts).

Answer (score 3):

Some online sources will say this is the Javanese Pelog scale, but the Javanese tuning and scale system is very complex, it isn't the same tuning as Western scales, and whatever music these pitches come from might not necessarily be Javanese music.

At least superficially, these tones sounded to me like Javanese or Indonesian music, but it might not be appropriate to say this a Pelog scale. I only know enough to make a superficial association, because I like listening to it, but suspect I misunderstand a lot about that type of music.

Comment: If we want to avoid scales with non-western tuning, we could also say it's a pentatonic subset of the Phrygian mode.